# modrewrite Navigation path with Joomla result in Apache error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, joomla, joomla1.7

There is a website in Joomla, the NavigationPath ist domain.tld/index.php/produkte/produkt1.html this work fine. But now i activate the SEF URL Button and Joomla generate a link like: domain.tld/produkte/produkt1.html and this did not work. I rename the htaccess.txt to .htaccess and restart Apache. Modrewrite is enable. I have no experience in Joomla so i dont know how to solve it. Can anybody help me?

Here is the Joomla SEO Section:

[image: Joomla SEO Section]

My .htacces Code

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

When i try to access domain.tld/produkte/produkt1.html i get following Error in apache error.log:

```
[Thu Mar 29 15:36:49 2012] [error] [client 10.1.1.10] File does not exist: /var/www/produkte, referer: http://domain.tld/
```

And the Browser shows me:

```
The requested URL /produkte/produkt1.html was not found on this server.
```

Any suggestion to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that you have the correct file name for the file .htaccess

Check that your server admins haven't changed the name the server uses for these files - it is configurable so it is possible (though unlikely) that the file needs to be called something else

Add this line to your .htaccess file
immediately after the RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteBase /
```

Some servers also don't like the 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
you might try commenting that out by placing a # symbol at the start of the line

Comment: i explicite set the name of the .htaccess log in the apache config and now it works. thx

Answer (score 1):

Try to check this line in your configuration.php file:

```
var $live_site = 'http://mydomain.ext/joomlafolder'
```

where `mydomain.ext` is your website's domain and (this is obviously optional) `/joomlafolder` is your installation folder.

Comment: In my configuration.php there is public $live_site = 'http://domain.tld'; joomla is in the root for Apache /var/www/ But it dosent help.